# Is it possible that the soldiers near Pontius Pilate were less in number than the people in the crowd at Jesus' trial?

Tags: history, historical-interpretation, gospels, crucifixion

> Matthew 27:24 KJV — When Pilate saw that he could prevail nothing, but
> that rather a tumult was made, he took water, and washed his hands
> before the multitude, saying, I am innocent of the blood of this just
> person: see ye to it.
>
> Mark 15:15 — And so Pilate, willing to content the people, released
> Barabbas unto them, and delivered Jesus, when he had scourged him, to
> be crucified.

The Gospels indicate that Pilate commanded that Jesus be crucified because he did not want the Jews to get violent, and he wanted to appease them. Critics of the Gospels say that Pilate would not have done this, because he hated Jews and had no issue with killing them, as evidenced by the fact that he commanded a large group of Samaritans (who were not Jews ethnically but shared the culture and religion of the Jews, as far as one can tell) be slain for no clear reason. Josephus, moreover, says that Pilate was "naturally inflexible", and so it is unlikely that he would have changed his mind concerning releasing Jesus.

However, is it not possible that the Jews in the crowd demanding Jesus' death had weapons and were more numerous than the soldiers that Pilate had near him, and that, in an attempt to save his own life from the Jews (who almost certainly hated him personally at this point), he relented? According to the Encyclopaedia Brittanica, Josephus depicted Pilate as rational and practical. We know that there were soldiers at the trial, but is there any indication in the text of precisely how many soldiers there were? Is it possible that the number of soldiers at the trial was different (if so, presumably less) because the trial took place during the very early morning?

Thank you.

It's important to note, by the way, that there is no account of Pilate having killed large groups of Jews. In fact, he threatened to kill a large group of Jews who were protesting his bringing of images of Caesar into Jerusalem, but took the images out of the city when the Jews said that they would rather die than see Moses' Law broken and did not harm them. He did kill that large group of Samaritans, but, firstly, they were Samaritans, and, secondly, that was three to six years after Jesus' trial, if that is relevant. He is, however, said to have not respected the Jewish religion, which is much different than killing Jews, of course.

Comment: Quenching rebellions and provoking them are two distinct things.

Comment: @Lucian I agree, but what in the question made you say this?

Comment: The middle sentence of your first post-quotation paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. Do you believe that my suggestion in the question is plausible?

Comment: Honestly, little of what you wrote in this post seems to make any sense, either militarily or scripturally. Throughout human history, it was usually skill rather than numbers that determined the outcome of battles; numbers only then mattered when fighting skills were equally matched (e.g., the Spartan 300 decimated thousands of so-called Immortals on the battle field; invading Mongol hordes were no match for Western European mounted knights in full armor; etc). Biblically, the real reason is spelled out in John 19:12.

Comment: @Lucian I'd have to disagree with your points. Firstly, there were more than 300 soldiers who fought for the Greeks at the Battle of Thermopylae, although there were 300 Spartans. Secondly, all of the Greeks in the battle were killed, which proves my point. Thirdly, I don't see how a large group of Jews with weapons could not achieve their goal of attacking Pilate, which the text suggests they were intending to do, if the group of soldiers defending him was small enough. I can easily see one hundred or so armed Jews overpowering 15 Roman soldiers, for example. And, if the numbers were like

Comment: this, why would Pilate take the risk? Finally, even after the Jews accused Pilate of rebelling against Caesar, he tried to reason with them before giving Jesus up, as John 19:14-15 indicate. This is when Pilate would have desired to tame the crowd by giving up Jesus, as the other texts say. God bless.

Comment: I honestly don't recall saying that they lived to tell the story, and my points aren't *mine* to begin with, since I didn't exactly invent them. The Romans did not conquer the world by outnumbering their enemies on the battlefield; quite the contrary. In ancient times, as today, triumph is usually a result of having well-trained, well-organized, well-funded men. Why do you think that all civilized Western countries abandoned conscription in favor of skilled professionals ? Why do you think Russians suffered such terrible losses in the two World Wars, despite having numbers on their side ?

Comment: @Lucian After researching this issue further, I have found that there are other explanations for Pilate's behavior that may be more probable. I suggest this article. www.tektonics.org/gk/jesustrial.php#jn8. The link doesn't seem to be working properly, so the name of the article is "The Trial of Jesus: Authentic Historical Account" on Tektonics.org, if you care to read it.

Comment: I am familiar with *Tektonics*.

Answer (score 1):

The question probably is not so much whether Pilate had fewer soldiers than the number of the crowd at that particular time, but rather whether he would have had enough soldiers to quell any rebellion that would have broken out.

I think the answer is no.  At the time of the First Jewish Revolt 30 years later, the then governors of Judea had to ask Nero to send troops to help.  Since this was at a time of even more heightened difficulties with the Jews, we could imagine that even fewer troops were on hand for Pilate.

---

Josephus, in Book 2, Chapter 18 of *The Jewish War*, wrote:

> But when the governors of the Roman provinces throughout the world
> heard of the revolt and the destruction of the Roman garrison, they
> were horrified and immediately dispatched reinforcements to Judea. The
> emperor Nero also sent Vespasian, a distinguished general, to the
> region with three legions of soldiers, while his son Titus was
> appointed second in command. These legions were the fifth, the tenth,
> and the fifteenth, each consisting of 6,000 infantry and 120 cavalry.